# Sublime Text 2: Error trying to parse nonexistent ColorConsole file

Tags: xml, sublimetext2

I'm using the [ST2 Color Console](https://github.com/ehamiter/ST2-Color-Console) package. It works great, but recently I've been getting the following error on launch:

```
Error loading syntax file "/Users/******/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/ColorConsole/Console.tmLanguage": 
Error parsing plist xml: 
Failed to open file In file "/Users/******/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/ColorConsole/Console.tmLanguage"
```

Similar questions on Stack Overflow indicate this means ST2 is trying to parse a file that doesn't contain valid XML/JSON (in this case, it appears to be looking for XML). But neither the file nor the folder exists. There is no ColorConsole folder inside my ~/Sublime Text 2/Packages/ directory.

I tried creating a dummy "Console.tmLanguage" file at the target location like so:

```xml
<dict>
</dict>
```

This suppresses the original error, but now ST2 gives me  "Bad XML" error instead. I'm out of ideas. I'm not sure why it's looking here in the first place. The package works fine. Any ideas how to suppress the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Github repo you linked to, you'll see that, in fact, `Color Console` *does* include a file named [`Console.tmLanguage`](https://github.com/ehamiter/ST2-Color-Console/blob/master/Console.tmLanguage). Somehow that file got deleted on your system. Either delete and reinstall the package (you are using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io), aren't you?), or copy the raw contents of the above file to your dummy file, overwriting your "XML".

By the way, the reason your XML wasn't parsed as valid is because it lacks the proper structure of a [Property List](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/UnderstandXMLPlist/UnderstandXMLPlist.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- defines document as XML -->
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<!-- every document needs a doctype -->
<plist version="1.0">
    <!-- and at least the very outer container -->
</plist>
```

will do should you ever need a dummy `.tmLanguage` file again.